# Gif Animation Progress Bar for Windows 10 Desktop behaviour

Tags: animation, progress, gif

[image]

I am designing a native application which pushes windows bundles to Windows 10 desktop. Once the bundles are pushed from the native application you can install them on your desktop.

I need to give the mockup to the engineering team which shows the icon of the nativeapp for the bundles which comes from the native app. With that I also need to decide where the progress gif animation should be programmatically shown once the bundles are pushed via our app and gets installed, to keep the users alert that the application is being installed.

I tried checking the MSDN to see the default behavior but could not find any answer. Please help me review what I have in mind.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How to make .gif animated icons workable on a windows10 desktop overlaying on the main icons. The purpose is to show the indicative progress cycle like to denotes updates, install, download.